# Apple80211Associate2() failed with error -3905

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook-pro

I have been experiencing a bit of a problem with my MacBook Pro at work and our tech team don't seem to know how to resolve it without a full system reboot, which I would like to avoid. The problem is when I connect to a specific network I get this [image]

I am still able to connect to other networks it is just this one that I can't seem to connect to, but I can also still connect to this network with other devices it is just this one MacBook Pro that I can't connect with. I know the password is correct so it isn't that.

I have trawled through loads of sites over that the few days and found nothing, that explains why this is happening or how to resolve it. I found one site that said to run a script in terminal to get the error could so I did and here is the output I got.

```
Internets-MacBook-Pro:~ internet$ sudo /usr/libexec/airportd loggerWed Jan 23 09:14:33.998 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from pid 177 ().
Wed Jan 23 09:14:33.999 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Initiating scan.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:36.513 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for pid 177.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:37.0  <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from pid 177 ().
Wed Jan 23 09:14:37.0  <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Initiating scan.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:38.472 <airportd[2594]> ___createTerminateTimer_block_invoke_1: ...exiting
Wed Jan 23 09:14:39.492 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for pid 177.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:42.161 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::cachePurge: clearEntries[0] Firing!
Wed Jan 23 09:14:42.161 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::cachePurge: Rescheduling in 27 seconds.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:47.868 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Broadcast scan request received from pid 177 ().
Wed Jan 23 09:14:47.868 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::startScan: Initiating scan.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:50.351 <kernel> IO80211ScanManager::getScanResult: All scan results returned for pid 177.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:51.57  <airportd[2601]> _handleNewMessage: Received XPC message, event = ASSOC_EVENT, pid = 177
Wed Jan 23 09:14:51.60  <airportd[2601]> associate: INFO: airportd associate: network=<CWNetwork: 0x10da158f0> [ssid=RedSky, bssid=00:1d:e5:4f:ea:01, security=WPA2 Personal, rssi=-37, channel=<CWChannel: 0x10da185b0> [channelNumber=11(2GHz), channelWidth={20MHz}], ibss=0], is8021X=0, remember=1
Wed Jan 23 09:14:51.87  <airportd[2601]> associate: INFO: Checking if admin authorization is required
Wed Jan 23 09:14:51.119 <kernel> parseRSNIE: groupCipherType = 5 pairwiseCipherType = 5 authSel = 2
Wed Jan 23 09:14:51.119 <kernel> initWithInterfaceAndIE: _myMacAddress 60:33:4b:12:09:54
Wed Jan 23 09:14:51.119 <kernel> setPMK: PMK SET!
Wed Jan 23 09:14:54.851 <kernel> en1: Terminating supplicant.
Wed Jan 23 09:14:54.851 <kernel> RSNSupplicant: Releasing authenticator for 00:00:00:00:00:00
Wed Jan 23 09:14:54.851 <airportd[2601]> associate: Apple80211Associate2() failed with error -3905
Wed Jan 23 09:14:59.517 <configd[15]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/IOKit/PowerManagement/CurrentSettings' }
Wed Jan 23 09:14:59.518 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: check to see if AP on en1 is an iOS Personal Hotspot
Wed Jan 23 09:14:59.518 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: AP on en1 supports WoW
Wed Jan 23 09:14:59.693 <configd[15]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/IOKit/PowerManagement/CurrentSettings' }
Wed Jan 23 09:14:59.694 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: check to see if AP on en1 is an iOS Personal Hotspot
Wed Jan 23 09:14:59.694 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: AP on en1 supports WoW
Wed Jan 23 09:15:00.635 <configd[15]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/IOKit/PowerManagement/CurrentSettings' }
Wed Jan 23 09:15:00.636 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: check to see if AP on en1 is an iOS Personal Hotspot
Wed Jan 23 09:15:00.636 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: AP on en1 supports WoW
Wed Jan 23 09:15:00.810 <configd[15]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/IOKit/PowerManagement/CurrentSettings' }
Wed Jan 23 09:15:00.811 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: check to see if AP on en1 is an iOS Personal Hotspot
Wed Jan 23 09:15:00.811 <configd[15]> WoWiOSCapable: AP on en1 supports WoW
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo /usr/libexec/airportd logger
```

When I got this I started searching for errors associated with `Apple80211Associate2() failed with error -3905` and got quite a few I found a lot of forums say it was from an update to the OSX but I haven't done an update in a while as there is nothing to update.

I also had a look at [AirPort fails to connect to existing networks after Repairing Disk Permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/288963/airport-fails-to-connect-to-existing-networks-after-repairing-disk-permissions) but it doesn't explain how to solve this issue

Please can anyone help me resolve this issue it is putting a huge delay on my work.

Comment: (1) Is there any AirPort Express device in the network acting as AP? (2) Is there any Time Capsule device in the network acting as AP? (3) does the AP support 802.11n?

Comment: @JohnSiu Sorry what does AP stand for?

Comment: ap=access point = wifi

Comment: It just seem to stopped working and didn't give any indication to why.

Comment: I have found out and resolved this issue. The issue was the company I work for didn't know who the Mac Address belonged to so they blocked it. Even though I asked if it had been blocked and they said no we don't block devices on that network. Lost a week of major project time because of this. Thanks everyone.

Comment: AirPort Express wifi **do not** use password/key login but instead mac address list. That is why I ask if there is such an device. It is not completely accurate(though the result is same) statement that "they block your mac address", they **have to add it** into the list. Unless they actually removed your mac address ...

Comment: @JohnSiu I just received an email saying they had blocked it because they didn't know who it belonged to.

Comment: Then they actually removed it from the list because someone forget to fill in the info for your mac entry(The Airport Utility, software that configure/control Airport Express, allow a single line comment for each mac address).

Comment: @JohnSiu if you add your comments as an answer I am happy to give bounty to you as your the only one who has taken the time to try and help.

Comment: My pleasure. Answer created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Check if MAC address filtering is enabled on this network, and that your MacBook Pro's MAC address is in the list of allowed MAC addresses.

AirPort Expresses can be configured to filter clients based on a MAC address list. Any device whose MAC address is not in the list will not be able to join the Wi-Fi network.

In other words, every device connecting to an AirPort Express configured this way will need to have their MAC addresses entered into the MAC address list. This is done through the Airport Utility. AirPort Utility is available for OS X, iOS, and Windows. Additionally, AirPort Utility also allows a single line comment/note for each MAC address entry.

If a device was able to connect before, but can't now, then maybe its MAC address was actually removed from the list (maybe because someone forget to fill in the info for your MAC entry).

Comment: This answer is wrong. AirPort Expresses CAN and DO use passwords/keys for Wi-Fi authentication. They can also use MAC addresses. They can use one or the other or both or neither.

Comment: @Spiff check my PS, it is there. OP situation is MAC blocking.

Comment: @Spiff There has been plenty of time to give your input and he was correct in his comments, and he took the time to try and help which no one else did. So I am more then happy to accept this as answer and give the bounty too.

Comment: @John That PS doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Spiff but he is correct. If it helped and sorted the problem then it is an answer that can be accepted.

Comment: @JohnSiu I went ahead and edited it to focus on the real issue and remove the incorrect/misleading information.

Comment: @Popeye He was correct that your issue was MAC address filtering, but he was dramatically wrong when he claimed that AirPort Expresses "only" use MAC address filtering. I've edited his answer to only contain the correct information.

Comment: @Spiff also I really don't want to be rude so please don't take this the wrong way as I totally agree your bio, but if you don't have an a better answer how do you know its wrong. If you do have a better answer please do answer.

Comment: @Spiff Thank you for the editing and you are correct. For the various setup I checked, the `Wireless Security` is set none and use MAC filtering only. So you are correct that they can be used together if one choose to. Some how that wrong impression get into my head and nice someone corrected me :) (This is 10X much better than getting in the face on a client site, so really, thank you!!).